# Installing Imagemagick leads to weird error involving OpenCL

Tags: macos, opencl

I'm trying to install ImageMagick on Mac OSX 10.7 and I'm getting the following errors:

When I try to run the suggested verification

```
$ convert logo: logo.gif
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/convert
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

$ identify logo.gif
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/identify
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

When I try pretty much anything...

```
$ identify -version
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/identify
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've followed the path and it looks like the libclparser.dylib is missing from the OpenCL.framework, but I'm unsure of where to find that or how to replace it, or even if that's the right thing to do.

Comment: How is installing a library not programing related? Maybe this should be migrated to apple.stachexchange.com?

Comment: Or SuperUser ... it shouldn't have been just closed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix this.

1. Booted up my old machine running OSX 10.6.
2. Copied /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib from 10.6 computer into the same folder on 10.7.

Now things seem to be working fine.

**Note**: the file can also be found [here](http://www47.zippyshare.com/v/37898307/file.html):

Comment: Great, that worked for me too!  Thanks for posting it.

Comment: I copied my old file from a backup but it bummed out. The download link worked a treat. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone please re-upload ? The link is broke :(

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), try the following command:

```
brew doctor
```

to diagnose the common problems.

One of it could be to remove DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH variable from your ~/.profile if you have it.

Or you have to re-install libtool by:

```
brew reinstall libtool --universal && brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
```

Answer (score 2):

The top-voted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764176/lion-10-7-not-supporting-convert1-dylib-error (minus the first two steps) worked for me — so basically just

1. `brew uninstall imagemagick`
2. `brew update`
3. `brew install imagemagick`
4. (optionally) `brew doctor` and follow the instructions

I did have to manually delete some files, but `brew doctor` tells you which ones. The order of uninstall, update, install, doctor probably isn't important.

Comment: brew doctor checks things are OK so do first